# Is it OK to store a small object in the session?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session-variables

Users in my application can access different types of data based on what `marketplace` they are accessing.

So different data accessible by the user contain a `marketplace_id`. The Marketplace is a tiny model object containing only a marketplace name, id, and description.

Is it OK to store what marketplace the user is accessing in the session object? The object will never, ever change.

I want to store the whole object instead of just the id, because I have to reference the marketplace name on each screen.

Comment: The session object is just a hash, so I at present can't see any reason why that wouldn't work.

I believe that it might be better practise to associate it with your user object (assuming your users are indeed logged in) in the database though, because it'll mean that they can come back months later and start where they left off.

Comment: It is definitely associated with them. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on your specific application, but I would suggest not storing an object in the session. The main argument for avoiding this is that if you ever change the data in a Marketplace object, if you ever need to add/remove/change an attribute in the model, or if you ever want to add a method, you could have a serious problem on your hands.

Computers are really good at looking up entries in tables by ID, so generally speaking I wouldn't worry about the extra load you might incur from this sort of lookup. If it were an issue, I would look at caching this data on the server side.

Here's a [railcast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/13-dangers-of-model-in-session) about this very issue. Again, you should totally make your own decision, but these are the reasons to avoid it.

Comment: +1 to just storing the ID and then looking it up when needed.

Comment: Done and Done. The only reason I need it is for the id and the name, so I just made a session variable for each. Thanks!